# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания

Tags: запятая

Мне кажется, что в предложении знаки препинания расставлены неправильно: Или говоря языком лозунгов: "Это нужно не мертвым, это надо живым!" Потому что "народ, забывающий прошлое, не имеет будущего".
Перед потому что, наверное, нужна запятая, "или" вообще неуместно, говоря языком лозунгов нужно выделить запятыми. Это мое мнение. Права ли я, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сама фраза, конечно, не очень ... Даже по содержанию. "Это нужно — не мертвым! Это надо —
живым!" - не лозунг, это стихи Рождественского.

"Или" говорит о парцеллированной конструкции. Это возможно в художественной и публицистической речи.

Если не говорить о самой фразе, запятые возможно расставить так:

Или, говоря языком лозунгов, "это нужно - не мертвым, это надо - живым!", потому что "народ, забывающий прошлое, не имеет будущего". "Это цитирование, введённое в предложение.

Если же не сохранять пунктуацию Рождественского и считать его слова ставшими лозунгом, что-то менять, можно без кавычек, как слова, ставшие всеобщим мнением:Или, говоря языком лозунгов, это нужно  не мертвым, это надо  живым, потому что "народ, забывающий прошлое, не имеет будущего".

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо, я что-то совсем запуталась, теперь все понятно. Вы вообще объясняете доступно. Спасибо.